# mvc/JQuery - Post a form Viewmodel with an array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

There may be a better way of doing this.
In my form the user can enter a list of streetnames as follows:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="StreetName">By Street Name(s) </label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget col-md-6">
            <input id="StreetName" style="width: 500px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 0; vertical-align: top">
            <label for="StreetNameList">Selected Streetnames List:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5" style="height: 200px; width: 600px; overflow: auto; border: gray solid 1px; background: whitesmoke">
            <div id="StreetNameList" name="StreetNameList" style="height: 200px; width: 600px;"></div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StreetNames)
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the user clicks the submit button, the streetnames are put into the hidden field m.StreetNames which is a string array.
See

```
$("#submitdata").click(function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    var streetnames = [];
    var streetnamestring;
    $.each($("#StreetNameList .street"), function (i, $street) {
        streetnames.push($street.innerHTML);
    });

    $("#StreetNames").val(streetnames);
    $form.submit();
 });
```

On the view model, StreetNames is defined as

```
public string[] StreetNames { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when the Controllor action method receives the view model, only the first item is populated, and it contains the whole array delimited by commas.
How do I fix this so I get an array posted instead?

Comment: The code you have shown is not clear. You don't have any elements with `class="street"`. There is no need to use a hidden input. If you have multiple inputs for adding street names (not clear from the code you have shown) then so long as those inputs have the correct `name` attribute, your property will be correctly bound (no javascript required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is posting a string with a separator character which I used to split the string into an array on the server side. It looks like it was the only solution short of a rewrite and use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to post your request
You can use Ajax instead and all you have to do is set traditional in ajax request to the value true

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "youraction",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: {
        //your data
    }
});
```

Comment: To use an Ajax call will require a lot of code to change. I might do it if no one else comes up with an answer.

Comment: Since javascript variable/ojects uses dynamic datatype based on value assigned, there is no direct way to map them directly to the C# equivalents. JSON bridges this gap and ajax provides efficient way to get it done.

Comment: @NZeta520, The `DefaultModelBinder` reads the form data's name/values pairs. So long as the name attribute of the control matches a model property name then it will be correctly bound. Ajax and JSON are not required for this